# Define sort property for referenced field during order by in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-data-rest

I have rest repository with 2 entities and projection:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Language language;
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
}

@Projection(name = "details", types = {Person.class})
interface PersonProjection {

    Long getId();

    String getName();

    @Value("#{target.language.name}")
    String getLanguage();
}
```

When I'm trying to sort it by language field

> /api/persons/?projection=details&sort=language

it produce SQL that trying to sort it by language.id

> select person0_.id as i... order by **language1_.id** asc limit ?

Is there a way to tell Spring Data, JPA to use different default property for sorting without explicitly specifying it in url?

Comment: There's an example here of how to customize the search/sort bindings https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-web-support

Answer (score 1):

Spring data-rest as you configured it uses property traversal on your entity objects.
In your case, for Person and Language you have a name clash on the property "name".
In order to solve this issue your sort param should reference the correct property, i.e:
For sorting by language name your url should be like /api/persons/?projection=details&sort=language_name
For sorting by person's name your url parameter shoud look /api/persons/?projection=details&sort=person_name

Answer (score 0):

First override the `findAll()` method in your `PersonRepository` interface:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Override
    @Query
    public Iterable<User> findAll();
}
```

Then add a named query to your `User` entity class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query="select p from Person p order by p.language.name")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    Language language;
}
```

Comment: it will work only if I need to have it sorted by language all time. What if request will be _/api/persons/?projection=details&sort=name_ ?

Comment: Just add another named query.